# Not getting "Peer Pressure" badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I deleted these posts, but I did not get the Peer Pressure badge.

[image]

Comment: This is by design - the peer pressure badge is awarded at a post score of -3 not -2

Comment: but i shows -3 or lower. i have lower score -2.

Comment: `-2` is not "lower" than `-3`. Quite the opposite, in fact.

Comment: ok now i understand -4 is lower

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the posts you deleted didn't have the [required score of -3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) or lower.

Those answers scored `-2`, meaning they don't qualify for the badge.

To clarify:

"Score of -3 or lower" means that the Q/A has gotten least 3 downvotes, after adding the upvotes. So, for example, `+2/-5 = -3` or `+1/-6 = -5`. With `+2/-3 = -1`, you wouldn't get the badge.

Comment: score of -3 or lower here means what?. But i have -2 negative score.

Comment: _"Score of -2 or lower"_ means that the Q/A has gotten least 3 downvotes, after adding the upvotes. So, for example, `+2/-5 = -3` or `+1/-6 = -5`. With `+2/-3 = -1`, you wouldn't get the badge.

Comment: @Cerbrus You're repeating what I have said in my comments and answered (score =  vote, in this context, which the OP is comparing with reputation). For your information, if the OP had a net of 3 negative scores (down votes) initially and then subsequently earned up votes, he would still get to keep the badge, regardless.

Comment: @Unheilig: your answer is 50 minutes older than mine. How am I repeating what you said?.

Comment: @Cerbrus Your comment (15 mins. ago), not your answer. Your answer does not reflect that.

Comment: @Unheilig: That comment explains that upvotes cancel out downvotes, as far as the badge is concerned.You never mentioned upvotes in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The -4 means you have had 2 down votes, which comes to a total of 4 negative points (reputations).

The "qualification" for the badge requires at least 3 down votes (-3), which come to a total of 6 negative reputations.

Your confusion seems to be that, you are comparing "votes" with reputations. The -3 of the requirement is in ***votes*** (-3 votes = -6 ***reputations***).

The negative points you see from your reputation history, however, is in points. That is to say: -4 points = 2 down votes, which has yet met the requirement for the badge, which requires at least 3 down votes - at least a total of -6 points (reputations).

> Delete own post with a -3 score or lower.

Rephrasing it:

Delete own post with at least 3 down votes (at least -6 reputations).

Comment: _"-3 score"_ is not the same as _"3 downvotes"_. 3 dvs and 1 up would result in a -2 score.

Comment: My point is that: _"Delete own post with at least 3 down votes (at least -6 reputations)."_ is incorrect. Reputation doesn't matter, and it looks at the _net_ vote count, not just the amount of downvotes.

Comment: That `-4` isn't called the _"Score"_. That `-4` is _"reputation"_. The _score_ is the net amount of _votes_ you got. The badge requires a _score_ of -3 or lower.

Comment: @Cerbrus If you did read my answer all along, -4 equals to reputation, not score. Score, as mentioned in my answer, is vote.

Comment: Like I said, my point is that: _"Delete own post with at least 3 down votes (at least -6 reputations)."_ is incorrect. That last sentence in your answer is not how the badge works.

Comment: @Cerbrus I stand by my answer; my point was to clarify to the OP that his confusion stemmed from the fact that he is comparing reputations with scores (votes).
Hence, when he saw he had a -4, he thought he should have had the badge because he thought -4 means score, when -4 actually means reputation, which equals to 2 scores (down votes). It is the conversion that confuses him.

Comment: @Unheilig I'm confused here. Score != votes, correct? You can have 10 votes (up or down) but the score of your post could be 0, right? So when you say *'...comparing reputations with scores (votes)'* that is incorrect unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Unheilig Thanks for your reply. What I'm saying is that `rep` is not the same as `votes` which is not the same as `score`. They are all closely linked but if you get 3 votes you don't necessarily have a score of 3 (it could be -3 or 2 or whatever). Ultimately you cannot have -3 votes, can you? You could have -3 score but you cannot have -3 votes. Maybe I'm missing the point and debating apples and oranges but it's the difference that is the confusion, I think.

Comment: @Henders Analogy: he had 4 quarters (USD), which he compares to 3 dollars. In the OP's mind: 4 > 3. The unit conversion seems to have confused him.